# Twin wire neutral

Tags: power-engineering, neutral

I work in the power distribution industry and recently came across a 3-phase LV circuit with "twin-wired neutral" (i.e. two neutral cables inter-winded, therefore five cables total). What would be the point of such a neutral configuration? Would this be to carry more current due to neutral currents/unbalanced phases?

Cheers!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Possibly a diagram? I am certainly no expert, but I am unsure what you mean by `twin wire neutral`? Was it just two wires connected to the same nodes?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are right, probably is to handle more current due to unbalance.  Neutral cable's section for distribution transformer, should be the same as the phase conductor.